# Glue to attach rubber feet to a PC case?

Tags: ibm-pc, restoration, case

I have an old PC case. I spray painted it because it was a little bit rusty. Now I'm trying to attach a set of rubber feet to it, but I have no idea what kind of glue to use.

I tried hot glue, but it didn't hold at all. Superglue dissolves rubber, and I think most two-component glues would too. What would you use?

Comment: Sounds like perhaps the problem is the paint itself not sticking well.  Can you sand or file off the paint where you want to put the feet?  Or alternately add a coat of polyurethane gloss?

Comment: The rubber feet didn't have sticky tape on them?

Comment: It probably had around 1995.

Comment: Two-component (resin-type) glues should not damage rubber. You should just make sure to pick one that sets into an elastic bond, not a hard one. Most manufacturers I know state that on the package.

Comment: If the rubber feet you're using are 25 years old, perhaps you should purchase some new ones?  They're pretty cheap and the glue they come with is likely to work better than most other things.  Rubber that old is likely to be at the point where it's starting to degrade anyhow.

Comment: Are you stuck on glue?  Many computer cases had two-part feet with a pad that clicked into a hole, and then a plastic pin up through the middle to deform the clip and hold it.

Comment: The set I have at hand is the sticky kind, but without the self-adhesive layer because it came off during cleaning. I just checked on eBay, but the ones I found are ridiculously overpriced (~$15 for the set and ~$20-25 for shipping to Canada) and those that aren't refuse to ship outside the US.

Comment: Even considering the shipping cost, you'd be better of checking an electronics supplier instead of ebay.  If you do, keep in mind that they are sold individually so you'd want to order at least 4.  For example, here's a parametric search on  [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/f3vtz4z2); prices start at ~USD0.10 each.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A thin plastic tape with strong adhesive on both sides is what I usually use for these types of applications.  The tape I use is [Scotch 665 double-coated tape](https://www.scotchbrand.com/3M/en_CA/scotch-brand-ca/all-products/products/%7E/Scotch-Double-Sided-Tape-665-C-0-47-in-x-25-yd-12-mm-x-22-9-m-boxed-2-per-pack/?N=4335+3293569191+3294529206&rt=rud); it's a bit hard to find but an electronics supplier (e.g. [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/short/d7zbv40p), quantity of 1 in various sizes) or industrial supply house (e.g. [Grainger](https://www.grainger.com/search?searchQuery=Scotch+665&searchBar=true) , in quantities of 36) should stock it.  You could also try a double-sided tape sold for home/office use such as [Scotch 667-ESF](https://www.scotchbrand.com/3M/en_CA/scotch-brand-ca/all-products/products/%7E/Scotch-Double-Sided-Tape-667-ESF-3-4-in-x-11-1-yd-19-mm-x-10-1-m-/?N=4335+8709316+8709342+8710660+8710804+8711017+8711729+3292165439&rt=rud); it's widely available at retail but might not hold as well.

Comment: Double-sided carpet-fitting tape is good: stronger than office type but quite easy to get

Comment: Home Depot carries several varieties of 3M / Scotch 2-sided mounting tapes, some of which are extremely strong. Usually on display in the paint department.

Comment: These tapes benefit from having a smooth, clean mounting surface and — critically — pressure being applied at time of joining. I wish I'd known that years ago, or I wouldn't have had so many rubber feet fall off.

Answer (score 7):

I find this website helpful for similar questions: https://thistothat.com/
"We are here to help you choose the right glue for your bonding requirements"

Rubber to Metal
For the strongest bond, we recommend:

```
Household Goop
```

Not as strong but good for a large area is:

```
3M 80
```

Comment: It's actually "Rubber to Paint" in OP's case, but the site doesn't have an option for that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

I have actually used superglue (cyanoacrylate) for this without ill effects.  It's not solvent-based and doesn't dissolve rubber (even natural rubber, which this probably isn't).  The downside is it's brittle, but for feet that's OK unless you make a habit of dragging the case around.  Some "rubber" materials don't bond well, but [adhesive companies recommend trying cyanoacrylate first](https://www.permabond.com/resource-center/rubber-bonding-type-rubber-unknown/).  That link is worth a reda as it mentions degreasing the surface first, and a few other tips. Superglue should also stick to the paint fairly well, though a bit of roughening may be in order.

2-part epoxies again aren't solvent-based and won't attack the rubber, but they don't bond to it as well as superglue, and the rubber easily peels off.

Comment: Cyanacrylate is a bad idea for sticking rubber to solids. It sets into a hard crystalline layer, and soft/elastic materials like rubber peel off of that rather easily.

Comment: @WooShell I defer to the expert I linked to (you may wish to use a rubber-toughened variety though, as those are more flexible).  Peel forces aren't likely to be significant when the joint is in compression, as with a case foot, but that's why I mentioned the risk of dragging it around.  I've done this on a few things, including heavy lab equipment that has to be dragged out from under benches

Comment: @WooShell Unless you use rubberized/flexible cyanoacrylate (Loctite 4902 for example)

Answer (score 4):

3M VHB (very high bond) double-sided tape is your friend.  Not only will it not fall off, you will have trouble pulling it off once it cures.

Comment: Welcome, Bob! VHB is great if both surfaces are absolutely clean and you provide the right amount of pressure on application. Without these details it can be challenging to use.

Answer (score 1):

I use Fix-All Adhesive (by Superglue Corp) for most everything.  I have rubber feet held onto a computer with it for years.  Not magical, but it works. Can be found in 5/8 fl oz tubes in $1 stores, or double that price if you order online.  It stays a bit flexible and can be peeled off for easy cleanup.  Doesn't handle UV (sunlight) particularly well.